# Jgit Usage without installing Git

Tags: java, git, jgit

Can I use JGit , without installing Git on my machine?

I was thinking whether it is necessary to have git installed before working on Jgit, or JGit provides a portable git version of its own?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly the point of JGit: it's a pure Java *implementation* of Git, which can be easily used from JVM applications or libraries.

Comment: That's only half the truth, jgit might behave differently if you have git installed. Most git filter are executed via command line.